# Reusing parent context with context.WithTimeout in go?

Tags: go

### Reusing parent context with context.WithTimeout with a new timeout

Hi there, I'm new to `go`. I was wondering if it's possible to reuse a parent context to create multiple context.withTimeout(). The rationale would be where I have to call multiple network requests in sequence and would like to set a timeout for each request at the same time using the parent's context.

### Rationale

When the parent's context is cancelled, all the requests made would be cancelled too.

### Problem

In the code below, it shows an example whereby `LongProcess` is the network request. However, the context is closed before the second `LongProcess` call can be made with a `context deadline exceeded`.

The documentation `withDeadline` states `The returned context's Done channel is closed when the deadline expires, when the returned cancel function is called, or when the parent context's Done channel isclosed, whichever happens first.`

So if that's the case, is there a way where I can reset the timer for withTimeout? Or do I have to create a new context `context.Background()` for every request? That would mean the parent context will not be passed. :(

```
// LongProcess refers to a long network request
func LongProcess(ctx context.Context, duration time.Duration, msg string) error {
    c1 := make(chan string, 1)
    go func() {
        // Simulate processing
        time.Sleep(duration)
        c1 <- msg
    }()

    select {
    case m := <-c1:
        fmt.Println(m)
        return nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    t := 2 * time.Second

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, t)
    defer cancel()

    // Simulate a 2 second process time
    err := LongProcess(ctx, 2*time.Second, "first process")
    fmt.Println(err)

    // Reusing the context.
    s, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, t)
    defer cancel()

    // Simulate a 1 second process time
    err = LongProcess(s, 1*time.Second, "second process")
    fmt.Println(err) // context deadline exceeded
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the first call to `context.WithTimeout` shadow the parent context `ctx`. The later process re-use this already canceled context hence the error. You have to re-use the parent one. Here is the example updated:

```
func main() {
    // Avoid to shadow child contexts
    parent := context.Background()
    t := 2 * time.Second

    // Use the parent context.
    ctx1, cancel := context.WithTimeout(parent, t)
    defer cancel()

    err := LongProcess(ctx1, 2*time.Second, "first process")
    fmt.Println(err)

    // Use the parent context not the canceled one.
    ctx2, cancel := context.WithTimeout(parent, t)
    defer cancel()

    err = LongProcess(ctx2, 1*time.Second, "second process")
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```